# Exporting Python Counter to .CSV file

Tags: python, csv, io, counter

I have script that opens and reads text file, separate every word and making a list of those words. I made Counter to count each word from list how many times does it appears. Then I want to export in .csv file each row something like this:

word hello appears 10 times

word house appears 5 times

word tree appears 3 times

...And so on

Can you show me what do I need to change here to make script to work?

```
from collections import Counter
import re
import csv

cnt = Counter()

writefile = open('test1.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(writefile)


with open('screenplay.txt') as file:       #Open .txt file with text
    text = file.read().lower()
    file.close()
    text = re.sub('[^a-z\ \']+', " ", text)
    words = list(text.split())             #Making list of each word
    for word in words:
        cnt[word] += 1                     #Counting how many times word appear
        for key, count in cnt.iteritems():
            key = text
            writer.writerow([cnt[word]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big issue is that your second for-loop is happening for every occurrence of every word, not just once for each unique word. You will need to de-dent the whole loop so that it executes after you have finished your counting. Try something like this:

```
from collections import Counter
import re
import csv

cnt = Counter()

writefile = open('test1.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(writefile)


with open('screenplay.txt') as file:
    text = file.read().lower()
    text = re.sub('[^a-z\ \']+', " ", text)
    words = list(text.split())
    for word in words:
        cnt[word] += 1
    for key, count in cnt.iteritems(): #De-dent this block
        writer.writerow([key,count]) #Output both the key and the count

writefile.close() #Make sure to close your file to guarantee it gets flushed
```

Comment: Thank you! It works, I was unorganized with code so I forgot for second loop to check.